# Python web-scraping go to next page

Tags: python, web-scraping, html

The code just prints the same email addresses again and again and doesnt go to the next page. Does anybody see the error in my code?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def get_emails(_links:list):
for i in range(len(_links)):
 new_d = soup(requests.get(_links[i]).text, 'html.parser').find_all('a', {'class':'my_modal_open'})
 if new_d:
   yield new_d[-1]['title']

start=20
while True:
d = soup(requests.get('http://www.schulliste.eu/type/gymnasien/?bundesland=&start=20').text, 'html.parser')

results = [i['href'] for i in d.find_all('a')][52:-9]
results = [link for link in results if link.startswith('http://')]
print(list(get_emails(results)))

next_page=d.find('div', {'class': 'paging'}, 'weiter')

if next_page:

    d=next_page.get('href')
    start+=20
else:
    break
```

When you press the button "weiter" (next page) the urlending changes from "...start=20" to "start=40". It is in 20s steps because there are 20 results per site.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `next_page` returns anything, the problem is you're trying to do the same thing twice at once, but neither are done properly:

1.) You're trying to point `d` to a the next page, and yet in the beginning of the loop you reassign `d` to the starting page again.

2.) You're trying to assign `start+=20` for the next page but you're not referencing `start` in any part of your code.

## Thus, you have two ways to tackle this:

1.) Move the `d` assignment outside of the loop, and remove the `start` object altogether:

```
# start=20
# You don't need start because it's not being used at all

# move the initial d assignment outside the loop
d = soup(requests.get('http://www.schulliste.eu/type/gymnasien/?bundesland=&start=20').text, 'html.parser')
while True:
    # rest of your code

if next_page:

    d=next_page.get('href')
    # start+=20
    # Again, you don't need the start any more.
else:
    break
```

2.) No need to reassign `d`, just reference `start` in your url in the beginning of the loop and remove the `d` assignment in the `if next_page`:

```
start=20
while True:
d = soup(requests.get('http://www.schulliste.eu/type/gymnasien/?bundesland=&start={page_id}'.format(page_id=start).text, 'html.parser')

# rest of your code

if next_page:

    # d=next_page.get('href')
    # this d assignment is redundant as it will get reassigned in the loop.  Start is your key.
    start+=20
else:
    break
```

Comment: I get this error with you code: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: The error is pretty descriptive is it not? Check your indent blocks to make sure you're indenting properly.

Comment: im new to python... but I still get an error: invalid syntax

Comment: My code now: import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def get_emails(_links:list):
    for i in range(len(_links)):
     new_d = soup(requests.get(_links[i]).text, 'html.parser').find_all('a', {'class':'my_modal_open'})
     if new_d:
       yield new_d[-1]['title']
    
start=20
while True:
    d = soup(requests.get('http://www.schulliste.eu/type/gymnasien/?bundesland=&start={page_id}'.format(page_id=start).text, 'html.parser')

# rest of your code
    if next_page:
        start+=20
             
    else:
        break

Comment: ... `# rest of your code` is meant for you to put in your code, not just copy and paste it.  I only made changes to the relevant part, you'll need to understand the changes and merge it into your existing code.  Unfortunately if you are unable to do that you have a much bigger problem than your initial question.

Comment: sure, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with url you are requesting. Same url is requested everytime because you are not updating the url as per start you are calculating. Try changing url like this:

```
'http://www.schulliste.eu/type/gymnasien/?bundesland=&start={}'.format(start)
```

Comment: I get this error with you code: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: If you can share description of your error.... This line of code won't cause indentation error. There must be some indentation error in your code, just see the line number its pointing to.